# logic for method to detect cycle in an undirected graph

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, undirected-graph, cyclic-graph

I was trying to detect a cycle in a directed graph. 
While coming up with the logic to solve it, I figured out that a simple graph traversal eq. dfs is sufficient because while doing dfs we can just have a condition to see if any node is already visited. If so, there must be a cycle.

While, looking up the solution to cross check my logic I came across [this solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph/) which says that while doing dfs along with keeping track of the visited nodes you also need to keep track of the nodes in the recursion stack and is a node is already in the recursion stack then there is a cycle- which I do not understand. 
 Why do we need to keep track of the nodes in the recursion stack when we can simply just check if a node is visited again and conclude there is a cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `undirected` graph, detecting a cycle is easy using `DFS`.
`Back-edge` is nothing but the edge between current node and it's ancestor which is not it's direct parent.
So, for a cycle in a graph, a node that is part of the cycle must connected to it's ancestor. This way the problem reduces to finding back-edge in the graph.
While applying `DFS` on `undirected` graph, we need to keep track of the parent of current node.
There is no parent of starting node, so we pass it's `parent = -1` in `DFS`. We call `DFS` again on child with it's parent as current node. Now we check if the visited child of current node is it's parent or not.
If the `visited child` is it's parent then no problem as it is not it's ancestor and we move to it's next child. But if the `visited child` is not it's parent then this visited child has to be it's ancestor and hence we got a back-edge.
Once we found back-edge we stop further `DFS` and return informing 'a cycle is present'. If we don't find a back-edge even if all nodes are visited, then cycle is not present in the graph.

```
bool dfs(int node,int parent,vector<vector<int>>&graph,vector<bool>&visited){
        visited[node]=true;
        for(int child: graph[node]){
                if(visited[child]==true){
                        if(child!=parent){ //backedge
                                return true;
                        }
                }
                else
                        return dfs(child,node,graph,visited);

        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DFS, we can detect an undirected graph. We use the visited list to check if the node is already visited or not and the parent identifies the parent of the node from the previous method's call.

Back edge is the edge between the current node and it's ancestor, not its parent. So, in order to have a cycle in a graph, a node that is part of the cycle must connected to its ancestor. While applying DFS on an undirected graph, we need to keep track of the parent of the current node. For each of the neighbor of the node, if the neighbor is visited and not the node's parent then we found the cycle. If the node is visited and it is the node's parent then we proceed with the next node. In case we haven't visited the neighbor before then we call DFS for this neighbor.
We need to add the condition

```
if(is_cyclic(n, node, graph, visited)):
    return True
```

for the corner case where the node has only one neighbor and this neighbor is its parent. Then, without this conditions and by just returning `return is_cyclic(n, node, graph, visited))` we skip the rest of the neighbors for a previous node.

For the first node we pass as parent a node that is not part of the graph.

```
def is_cyclic(node, parent, graph, visited):
    visited[node] = True
    for n in graph.neighbors(node):
        if visited[n]:
            if n != parent:
                return True
        else:
             if(is_cyclic(n, node, graph, visited)):
                 return True
    return False
```